# Where can I get standard OCR character images online?

Tags: resources, ocr

I need bitmap images for 0-9,a-z,A-Z.

Is there such resources online?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> as you are reading this.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

1. Open your favorite graphics editing program.
2. Paste.
3. Spend a few minutes copy-pasting.
4. Enjoy.

<sub>Yes, this is a little tongue-in-cheek, though it's a perfectly valid answer as well.</sub>

Comment: The bmp files generated this way is an indexed image(`[a map]=imread(path)`),but I want a non-indexed image.

Comment: Then save the files as a different format. That has nothing to do with the answer and everything to do with your choice of how to save the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after basic, crisp characters then how about the [Windows terminal font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(typeface))?

If you don't mind doing an *alt+print screen* followed by 26 + 26 + 10 *paste-crop-save* operations in Paint (or another graphics package) then you can see a good preview of each character in a bounding box using [Windows Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map).

Comment: I need separate ones for each character,though.